# Unable to start/delete Windows Service created under Local System

Tags: windows-services, service-control-manager

As part of an MSDeploy post step I run

`sc create MyService binPath= "C:\Services\MyService"`

(Note that this command is run from the remote server)

Trying to start/delete the service using `sc` or via the UI results in an `Access Denied` error which doesn't make sense. Why would the local system not be allowed to do that? You can't go to the service folder and add local system as a user..

**What am I doing wrong?**

If I need to use another account such as `Local Service` or `Network Service` how do I specify the account to use in my sc create command?

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, I specified the name of the directory rather than including the executable.

Apparently `sc` will still create the service without error.